# Can't post answer because Captcha hangs

Tags: support, bug

I can't post an answer because the Captcha hangs. It keeps spinning indefinitely when I check "I'm not a robot", and the reCaptcha button cannot be activated. I'm using Opera 12.x.

Is this something that can be fixed in SE software? (All things considered, I would rather not use a different browser.)

Comment: This is most likely not a SE problem, but something in your browser. Try rebooting the computer and/or reopening the browser.

Comment: @amoeba That might be it. For now I posted from a different browser...